# Wraping my python script as a linux daemon

Tags: python, service, compilation, cython

I have multiple python files and I want to install them as a service on the client's server.
The problem is that I dont want the client to have access to my code so I need to generate something like exe but for linux and as a service.

I thought about using cython but I wander if there is a easier way to do that. Of course I also have some packages I need to include in this "wrapping"

Comment: if you want to hide code then write in C/C++/Rust/Go

Comment: Linux for server often can use code directly in python and it doesn't need to convert to something line .exe - but tools like `pyintaller` only convert to self-extracting .zip file with python interpreter, modules and your code as `.pyc` which could be converted back to Python

Comment: there are modules to use Python as daemon in linux - ie. [python-daemon](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/)